# Quarkus OpenShift deploy works, but it is not rolled out

Tags: openshift, quarkus

Trying to deploy to OpenShift (4.x) with the latest Quarkus version. The deployment is done, but it is not rolled out (have to use oc rollout latest dc/.
Did I miss something in the configuration or is this the normal behavior?

Comment: How are you deploying the application? Also, what does your `application.properties` look like?

Comment: I'm using maven as build tool (jib for building docker container) and in the application.yml -file I have this "quarkus.kubernetes.deploy=true"

Comment: Tested with WSL2 on Windows - about the same behaviour. When I installed podman in WSL2 it worked right away - go figure!

Comment: Very weird indeed....